# Ошибка при запуске Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

При запуске VS 2019 выпадает ошибка(см. закреп). Еще вчера все работало нормально и корректно. Каких-то решений на просторах интернета, которые помогли бы решить эту проблему - не нашел.

Не удается найти один или несколько компонентов

[image: Ошибка]

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Переустанови её?

Comment: Кстати, там наверное и режим восстановления есть у студии, можно через него попробовать восстановить.

Comment: Дельную информацию пожалуйста 
KoVadim

Comment: Если студия вам сама предлагает её переустановить, то что вам не нравится, когда вам это и советуют? Но лучше всё же режим восстановления сначала попробовать.

Comment: @Memes - абсолютно дельная информация.